# Chrome fires drag events at wrong locations only when devtools are open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, google-chrome-devtools

I've been going somewhat crazy trying to debug a file drag and drop issue in an application I'm working on. What's happening is that Chrome is firing `onDragEnter`, `OnDragOver` and `onDrop` events (the only events I'm using) outside the element on which they're defined but **only** when devtools is open. I can't share my code but I can reproduce the issue easily using this bare bones example on JSBin: https://jsbin.com/hiqasek/edit?html,js,output

With devtools open, if I drag a file from Finder up toward the target div the `onDragEnter` event happens when the cursor is about 75 or 100 pixels below the div. If I go ahead and drop the file there the `onDrop` event fires. The end result is as expected but from the wrong cursor position. Now if I close devtools and do this again, the events fire "pixel perfect" inside the div.

Running in incognito mode with extensions disabled yields the same result.

My setup: MacOS 10.15.7 with Chrome 95.0.4638.69. This did not happen when testing with Edge 95.0.1020.40 and Safari 15 v15612.1.29.41.4.
EDIT: Does not happen in the same version of Chrome on Windows 10 20H2 (19042.1288)

Am I overlooking something (very possible), or is this is a bug in Chrome?